# How to fix java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to connect with a database and that seems to work fine. I created an object Producto and upload Producto into the database. I think the problem it's the form I created the database. I have 2 tables 1. with id_categories and the name of it. 2. This has the product with the name, id_Product, and also has the id_categories. The two tables are conected by the id_categories.

This is the error:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lacompraalegre`.`productos`, CONSTRAINT `id_categoria` FOREIGN KEY (`id_categoria`) REFERENCES `categorias` (`id_categoria`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

This is the code:

```
public void insertarProducto(Producto p) {
    try {
        String query = "INSERT INTO productos (nombreProducto, numeroExistencias, id_categoria) VALUES (?,?,?); ";
        con = conexion.conectar();
        PreparedStatement pst =  con.prepareStatement(query);
        try {
        pst.setString(1, p.getNombreProducto());
        pst.setInt(2, p.getCantidadExistente());
        pst.setInt(3, p.getId_Categoria());

        }catch(NullPointerException e) {
            logger.error("Algo ha ido mal");
        }

        int insertado = pst.executeUpdate();
        if(insertado>0) {
            logger.info("Insertado correctamente");
        }else {
            logger.error("No ha sido posible insertar usuario");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        ConectorBD.desconexion();
    }   
}
```

And the tables are [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVXyB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoEAU.png)

Comment: We can't really answer this question without seeing your data.  But, at the very least, you would need to show us the data you are trying to insert/update.

Comment: seeing the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` code for every table involved in the question to add to @TimBiegeleisen 's comment would also be very helpful so we can verify the correct datatypes.

Comment: You are trying to insert data into a table with a foreign key where the foreign key target data is missing.

Comment: In other words, you need to insert the parent record first, then insert the child record(s) with the matching primary key value from the parent table as the foreign key value in the child table.